# Want to connect any external device having bluetooth to the iphone through programatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

As I aware about Game-kit framework, i already used the session delegates and peerPickerController.
I want to connect any external device having bluetooth to the iphone through programatically, application will only executed on device, so i able to connect any external device and want to transfer data between them.
Can any suggest me solution.... waiting for reply..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with any external bluetooth device (that's not an iOS device) you need to use the [External Accessory Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html). I don't know the details, but my understanding is that you need to join the [MFi Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) before you can actually start any development.